# Python throwing multiple argument error when there is only one

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm calling a method in another class and I'm getting the following error.  This is the class that declares & defines the method:

```
from web import Web
import ast


class WebCrawler:
    web = Web()

    def crawl(self):
        root = self.root()
        URL = ast.literal_eval(self.get(root))
        return URL
```

And this is the class that calls it:

```
from web import Web
from crawler import WebCrawler

web = Web()
crawler = WebCrawler()
urls = crawler.crawl(web)

print(urls)
```

But the error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onur/Desktop/web-crawler/test-run.py", line 6, in <module>
    urls = crawler.crawl(web)
TypeError: crawl() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: `self` is the other argument. You need to accept another argument besides `self`.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik Yea but there isn't.  All I want to supply is web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance methods are implicitly passed the instance as the first argument (`self`). That means `crawler.crawl(web)` gets turned into `WebCrawler.crawl(crawler, web)`.

I'm not sure how to fix it since I'm not familiar with these modules, but I would guess that `crawl` is supposed to take an argument, since `WebCrawler` doesn't have a `root` method:

```
def crawl(self, arg):
    root = arg.root()
    ...
```